# console.log() for Shared WebWorker running in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a shared webworker running in my electron app.  I noticed that it doesn't print to the devtools console when using `console.log()`.  [This article](https://lihautan.com/Debugging%20web%20workers/) explains there's a way to inspect the shared webworkers using chrome's setting menu but since this is electron that isn't present.

Surely there has to be way to open another devtools console with the shared webworker context?

Comment: Can you try going through the remote debugging tools and seeing if you get more options there?  I'm not sure what electron's remote debugging port is, but it might be automatically discoverable through the `chrome://inspect/#devices` special page.  Maybe you can see it there.

Comment: Im seeing a `Remote Target` under localhost but not anything clickable.  Nothing under Shared Workers which makes sense as nothing is running in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never but I was having the same problem. In the end I found the following solution:

In your main process where you have your BrowserWindow use:

```
browserWindow.webContents.inspectSharedWorker();
```

This will open the devtools for the SharedWorker. You cannot have the normal devtools open at the same time, at least I haven't figured it out how to do that.

Only thing to remember is to call the function after you create the SharedWorker. So either use setTimeout or have a event that triggers it.